# Rest Easy Multipart Form data get files length for multiple files

Tags: java, httprequest, resteasy

I have requirement to create a service using rest easy which will consule multipart form data and I'm sending multiple files while calling this service and **@HeaderParam("Content-Length") int length** is giving total size of all files in the request . Is there any way to find seperately the size of all files coming in the request.

For example : If I'm sending two files in the request with 20 kb and 50 kb size , at present **@HeaderParam("Content-Length") int length** is giving me 70000 . Can I get size of two files seperately .

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by getting inputStream from MultipartFormDataInput  and then converted it into byte of array and hence lenght of array gives me the size of the file.